# Email Template preview

Tags: email, email-template

I want to show the email template of Visualforce type to user with the merge fields.
But when I try to fetch the Body or HtmlValue fields from EmailTemplate record it returns null.

Showing markup field value doesn't make sense to user.

How can I get the correct HtmlValue or Body?

Answer (score 2):

What I did to resolve this is copying the url of the 'manual' preview and putting that into an Iframe. I tested it for an HTML template but the same principle should work for a VisualForce template I'd think:

```
<apex:iframe title="Preview" 
             id="previewFrame" 
             scrolling="no" 
             frameborder="0" 
             height="961" 
             width="665" 
            src="{!ContentUrl}/email/templaterenderer?id={!templateId}&related_to_id={!theOpp.Id}&preview_frame=previewFrame&base_href={!BaseUrl}&render_type=REPLACED_HTML_BODY" />
```

The following APEX variables are used:

```
public Id templateId {
    get{
        if(templateId == null){
            EmailTemplate template = [select Id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'The_Email_Template'];
            templateId = template.Id;
        }
        return templateId;
    }
    private set;
}
public String getBaseUrl(){
    return System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
}
public String getContentUrl(){
    return System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm().replace('.visual.force.com','.content.force.com');
}
```

Lastly, theOpp.Id is in this case the Opportunity Id but can be any Id of the relatedto record for the email template.

Comment: Hey thanks! I do want the values to be replaced. The merge fields should be there as it is.

Comment: Aren't they fetched from the related_to_id? As stated, if works for me for normal email templates. So maybe it's a visualforce issue. If you could post the visualforce code (or a sample) I could have a look.

Comment: Currently, I have a dropdown where a list of VF templates is shown. When user selects a template, a remote action is called which returns the subject and body of the selected template. I am using jquery to dynamically inject this email template body in a div on my page as preview. Now, for VF template, it has all those messaging and apex tags which are not relevant to user. So I need something by which these tags are not shown by merge fields are shown as it is.

Comment: Can you help me on how the HtmlValue and Body field works for different types of email templates?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Your mechanism of creating a preview is really very different from what I did, so I'm afraid I can't help you with that. I did notice that when I load a preview of a VisualForce email template with my mechanism, it does fill the merge fields if I provide the related record Id in the url.